# Code from PHP to C#

Tags: c#, php, data-structures

i need your help.

i have the following data structure in php:

```
    $conditions = array(
            "START" => array(
                "AND" => array(
                    array("=="  => array( 'SessionId' => session_id())),
                    array("<=" => array( 'LastAction'=> time()-SESSION_LIFETIME))
                    )
                )
            );
```

i need this code in c# now. i have tried a mix of list and dictionaries... now im totally confused and lost in this mix...

any ideas?

thanks :)

Paul

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement it as a data structure.

You should write your own class as a container class and it should contain another class, and it should contain another and another...

May be you can get help from generic Lists or other container classes of .NET Framework